# How to select multiple shapes by name in PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
               With Slide.Shapes("BOXNAME")

Selects the box named BOXNAME how would I select multiple shapes by name at once?

Comment: Do you have multiple shapes with the same name?

Comment: Yes but on different slides. So for each slide I want to cycle through find if that slide has the shape BOXNAME1 or whatever and if it does to change the font.

Answer (score 5):

If the shapes are grouped, you can select them all simultaneously by selecting the group:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Group 7").Select
```

Otherwise, you can create an array of shape names, then select the array:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 6", "Rectangle 4", "AutoShape 5")).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the shapes to be named as BOXNAME1, BOXNAME2, ...

```
If i = 1 To 10
With Slide.Shapes("BOXNAME" & i)
On Error Resume Next
End With
```

This will condense multiple sub-routines into a single sub-routine.